# Warning Message: Missing columns filled in

Tags: r, warnings

I have a text file that I convert into a `data.frame` using this code:

```
library(auk)
practice_ebd <- "bar-tailed_godwit-2000-2020.txt" %>% read_ebd()
```

with this warning message:

> Warning message: Missing column names filled in: 'X47' [47]

What does this mean and should I be concerned?

Example of output code:

```
structure(list(checklist_id = "S53530969", global_unique_identifier = "URN:CornellLabOfOrnithology:EBIRD:OBS720726875", 
last_edited_date = "2020-04-09 23:16:21", taxonomic_order = 5822, 
category = "species", common_name = "Bar-tailed Godwit", 
scientific_name = "Limosa lapponica", observation_count = "12", 
breeding_bird_atlas_code = NA_character_, breeding_bird_atlas_category = NA_character_, 
age_sex = NA_character_, country = "Taiwan", country_code = "TW", 
state = "Chiayi County", state_code = "TW-CYQ", county = NA_character_, 
county_code = NA_character_, iba_code = NA_character_, bcr_code = NA_integer_, 
usfws_code = NA_character_, atlas_block = NA_character_, 
locality = "<U+5609><U+7FA9><U+9C32><U+9F13><U+6FD5><U+5730>IBA--<U+5168><U+5340>(Aogu Wetland IBA)(New)", 
locality_id = "L3980078", locality_type = "H", latitude = 23.5004231, 
longitude = 120.1357877, observation_date = structure(11210, class = "Date"), 
time_observations_started = "07:45:00", observer_id = "obsr1073600", 
sampling_event_identifier = "S53530969", protocol_type = "Historical", 
protocol_code = "P62", project_code = "EBIRD", duration_minutes = 225L, 
effort_distance_km = NA_real_, effort_area_ha = NA_real_, 
number_observers = NA_integer_, all_species_reported = TRUE, 
group_identifier = NA_character_, has_media = FALSE, approved = TRUE, 
reviewed = FALSE, reason = NA_character_, trip_comments = "(CWBF uploading notes: reporter:<U+76E7><U+51A0><U+5B89> <U+89C0><U+5BDF><U+65B9><U+6CD5>:<U+6B77><U+53F2><U+7D00><U+9304> fid=34420)", species_comments = "8<U+590F><U+7FBD>"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), rollup = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your package is using `readr::read_delim()` function to read the text file. That warning means that it is seeing 47 columns in the data, but doesn't see column headers for all 47 to use as column names. The sample data you provided only has 45 columns, all named, so it's likely your package is dropping the extra columns as part of its work.

There are a few ways you can get this error, including:

1. You have extra empty columns based on your file prep. (Excel can place extra columns in your file, for example.)
2. Your string columns aren't always delimited/quoted appropriately, so some rows look like they have extra columns.

I'd use `readr::read_delim()` to read in your file directly, and inspect the results to see whether it warrants further clean-up work. Not a complete answer, but hope it helps point you in the right direction.